# How to display a text and a slider in one line in HTML / CSS?

Tags: html, css, slider

I have the following two elements: a caption and a slider that I want to be displayed in one line, but I don't manage to do that.

What could I fix?

Thanks!

```css
#biasindex {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 15px;
  right: 200px; /* "#menu width" */
  font-size: 14px; /* change this value to increase/decrease button size */
  /* width: 2em;
   height: auto;*/
  z-index: 10;
  float: left;

}

.slidercaption {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="biasindex"><div class="slidercaption">bias index: </div><div class="slidercontainer"><input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="biasRange">
</div></div>
```

Comment: typo `slidecontainer ` in css styles...

Comment: Just update this code in your css `#biasindex {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 15px;
    right: 200px;
    font-size: 14px;
    z-index: 10;
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    /* white-space: nowrap; */
    align-items: center;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dispaly:flex` to wrap element.

Also use `.slidercontainer` in css instead `.slidecontainer`

```css
#biasindex{
display:flex;
}
.slidercaption {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.slidercontainer{
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="biasindex">
  <div class="slidercaption">bias index: </div>
  <div class="slidercontainer"><input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="biasRange">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use flexbox. Remove float and add display flex

Below is the modified code

```
#biasindex {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 15px;
  right: 200px; /* "#menu width" */
  font-size: 14px; /* change this value to increase/decrease button size */
  /* width: 2em;
   height: auto;*/
  z-index: 10;
  /*float: left;*/
  display: flex;
}

.slidercaption {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```